# Location-aware printing without Windows Professional or Enterprise

Tags: windows, windows-8, productivity, printing, geo-location

I am trying to switch default printer based on my location, which Microsoft explains how to do on its [support site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/automatically-switch-default-printers-between-home-work-or-school) ("Automatically switch default printers between home, work, or school").  However, this only applies to the Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate versions of Windows 8, and I have the Basic version.  Any ideas for a tool that would do this, preferably free?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Mobile Net Switch](http://mobilenetswitch.com/) which handles all that and more whenever you change the network you are connected with.

This can be used to setup the printer as well and has no need for the professional versions of windows.

Its not free though, costing 29€. It has a free full-function no-expiration trial that annoys one with a startup screen, said screen is gone after paying the fee.

For reference, there is a [similar question on SU](https://superuser.com/q/221735/116338).